# Cakephp change Project Folder Name

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to change the Project Folder Name In Cakephp.The Project Folder Name is OldProjectfFolderName and I want it to be *NewProjectFolderName*.

Some Pages are Not working in my project. I get error shown as:

```
opendir(/var/www/clients/client1/web4/web/**GalosTechSmartReporterOld**/app/Vendor/tcpdf/fonts/):
failed to open dir: No such file or directory [APP/Vendor/tcpdf/tcpdf.php, line 4154]
```

After that I've changed the file permissions and delete the cache in my project folder. But its not working too.

Can you please help me?

Comment: [Repeating a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26120064/cakephp-change-project-folder-name) will not make us answer faster or better, improving your question maybe will.

Comment: In `Config/core.php` check if `App.fullBaseUrl` is being used. If not, then you are using some custom code and we cant help you with out your posting it

Answer (score 0):

1. Download Entire Project to your system
2. The after change your project folder Name
3. and upload in to your server
4. change file permissions 777
5. its working now